# deadlock with double channel

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm trying to create a program that send strings to a pool of goroutines (through a channel). Once the goroutine have finish their job, they send some results (through an other channel).

The code is:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "sync"
import "bufio"

func worker(linkChan <-chan string, outChan chan<- string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, jobId int) {
   defer wg.Done()

   for url := range linkChan {
    // ...
     outChan <- url
   }
}

func main() {
    lCh := make(chan string)
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    outCh := make(chan string)

    urls := []string{}
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        for _, link := range os.Args[1:] {
            urls = append(urls, link)
        }
    } else {
        s := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        for s.Scan() {
            urls = append(urls, s.Text())
        }
    }

    num_worker := 10

    for i := 0; i < num_worker; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(lCh, outCh, wg, i)
    }
    for _, link := range urls {
        lCh <- link
    }
    close(lCh)

    for res := range outCh {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", res)
    }
    close(outCh)
    wg.Wait()

}
```

Running `echo "something" | ./main` cause a deadlock.

From what I've understood, `close(lCh)` should stop the `for url := range linkChan` loop. Am I wrong (it seems so since the code deadlock) ?

How can I resolve this deadlock ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I don't have the time to debug this code, but I see you're using goroutines inside a loop in an unpredictable way.

See https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

Comment: the unpredictable way is the fact that I'm passing the loop index (``i``) to the goroutine or the fact that I'm using the ``url`` iterator ?

Comment: The loop index must be done like this: `go func(i int) { worker(lCh, outCh, wg, i); }(i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pump the urls in a goroutine, otherwise the `outCh` will fill up which as you aren't emptying it.  This will stall all the workers and it will deadlock.

So re-arrange the code to look like this

```
go func() {
    for _, link := range urls {
        lCh <- link
    }
    close(lCh)
    wg.Wait()
    close(outCh)
}()

for res := range outCh {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", res)
}
```

And it will work fine

[Complete code](https://play.golang.org/p/dNJM3M8Xde)

Answer (score 0):

https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range :

> For channels, the iteration values produced are the successive values sent on the channel until the channel is closed. If the channel is nil, the range expression blocks forever.

You use `range` **before** close `outCh`. You have to close `outCh` after `wg.Wait()`, like in Nick`s answer.